# Draggable UITextView Not Responding

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, draggable

I have created a custom UITextView that need to be draggable, this is the code I use:

```
class DraggableView: UITextView {

var lastLocation:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)

override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
    super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    // Initialization code
    var panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"detectPan:")
    self.gestureRecognizers = [panRecognizer]

    self.editable = true
    self.selectable = true
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func detectPan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var translation  = recognizer.translationInView(self.superview!)
    self.center = CGPointMake(lastLocation.x + translation.x, lastLocation.y + translation.y)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // Promote the touched view
    //self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)

    // Remember original location
    lastLocation = self.center
}
}
```

The shows up but the problem is that I can't write anything or interact with it, I can only move it.

What is the problem?

Comment: It's definitely not that simple to make this work, I have the answer in ObjC but I don't' have time to translate it, but it's a lot more involved than what you have there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace the code

```
self.gestureRecognizers = [panRecognizer]
```

with

```
self.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
```

I think there must be a gesture whick belongs to gestureRecognizers to tell the textView to become first responder.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that fixed the problem